# Installed Apps are not visible in Android TV rails in development build

Tags: android, android-tv, android-launcher, google-people-api

I am trying to create a launcher on Android TV and not able to see Installed Apps and Your Apps Rail. I am getting apps list, apps drawables correctly but it's not loading on the view. This issue is occurring only on development build when launching app through android studio or dev apk.
I am not facing above issue on live build or if installing the app from Google Play.